# function that takes all form elements from a given form/container and creates a reusable object

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Ok, I am trying to create myself a reusable function that I can have ultimately return an object of all form elements in a given container such as a div, or a specific form. However I seem to be stuck with passing the actual container/form to my function so it can run over the elements.

currently I have:

```
function findAllFormElements(formElem)
{
    //detect all form elemets on the page in a given form/container
    formObj = {};
    $(formElem ':input').each(function(key, val)
    {
        $(document).append(val+'<br>');
    });
    console.log(formObj);
}
```

where `formElem` is expected to be the containing element/form element ie:

```
<div class="something">
   <input type="text">
   <input type="text">
   <input type="text">
   <input type="text">
   <select>
     <option></option>
   </select>
   <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

or

```
<form class="something">
   <input type="text">
   <input type="text">
   <input type="text">
   <input type="text">
   <select>
     <option></option>
   </select>
   <textarea></textarea>
</form>
```

both would be acceptable container types in the long run as some forms in this project don't actually have form tags.

grant it my current example isn't exactly portraying what I want per say as it spits things out to the console, and appends them to the `document` but then end result once I get how I can pass the `formElem` parameter correctly so I can get all input types from straight `<input>` tags to `<select>`, `textarea` will be an object of all the form elements where there id/name is the key for the object and there value if any is the value. Either way just trying to figure out whats the best tactic for this type of capture. so I can iterate over the elements and get this information.

Comment: You can get all form elements with `document.forms`, and all inputs of the first form with `document.forms[0].elements`. What do you want exactly? it isn't clear. To me it sounds like all you really want is `var formObj = document.forms`

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery's `.serializeArray()` we can easily grab those `<form>` elements and create an object from them...

```
$('form').serializeArray(); // will turn into a key/value object
```

Since you want certain `<div>` collections to be serialized just do:

```
//turn that div (filled with inputs) into a form element
var tempForm = $('<form />', { html: $('#yourDiv').html() });

var objResult = tempForm.serializeArray(); // now serialize
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/K592f/1/)

Comment: Note: serializeArray() will work on a collection of input elements. `objResult = $("#form :input").serializeArray()`

Comment: Do you mean a `<div>` with inputs?

Comment: no, just a collection of the inputs themselves. so if `#form` is your div, select the inputs inside of it.

Comment: Oh gotcha! Yeah that's a good point, might be easier to just do that, save it as a variable then serializeArray

Comment: `serializeArray()` all though a nice piece of functionality, still faults my needs unfortunately. This object I am attempting to use will be used to cross reference changes immediately on the fly, one draw back is we have fields that are disabled as well which don't appear to come back in the object, also checkboxes that aren't checked, are not included in the object and the ones that are come back with a value of "on" which isn't helpful either. Unfortunately I think overall I am stuck creating a custom solution so I can take things in the object and then compare on change